# Why the question "Convert *.mp3 to *.ogg on Android" was closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

The reason selected by the people who closed it looks ridiculous.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743671/convert-mp3-to-ogg-on-android

Comment: Lack of effort, poorly worded question, etc etc. Needs work to be answered.

Comment: The only indication he's even looking for a programming solution is in the comments. The question itself just looks like one of the many lost newbies who stumble onto Stack Overflow every day and ask random pseudo-technical questions that have no connection to the site's mission.

Comment: Problem solved; the question has been deleted. It's no longer closed for the wrong reason(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if it had not wrongfully been closed as off-topic it could still be closed as `not a real question`, the reason being that it is too vague. The only answer you could give would fit the conversion from any source format to any target format: Look at the specifications of both formats, think of an algorithm to map the header and an algorithm to convert the stream appropriately. Then apply those to the source file.

If at this point the question gets morphed into *"what is the algorithm to do that?"* you are again at `not a real question` since this basically now is a code request without any prior effort.

Comment: I agree with you that the truth reason could be "not a real question" or some of the reasons people pointed in comments. But it isn't off-topic. Although I think that the questions like "what is the right library to do that?" or "what is the algorithm to do that?" are correct, IMHO.